# Form Not Clearing after submit POST AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, yeoman

I'm using angularjs frontend and Play framework backend to process posted data.

The challenge i'm facing is that the form is not resetting after successful posting of data I click submit.

My View is as below and is as below.

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit="signup()" novalidate>
 <div>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
          ng-model="email">
   </div>
 <div>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" id="password"
          placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">

 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up!</button>
</form>
```

My Angular controller is as below

```
angular.module('clientApp')
   .controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
     $scope.signup = function() {
       var payload = {
         email : $scope.email,
         password : $scope.password
       };

       $http.post('app/signup', payload)
           .success(function(data) {
             $log.debug(data);
           });
     };
   });
```

I'm using chrome browser. How do i get to clear the email and password fields after clicking submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `$scope.email` and `$scope.password` to `null` like

```
$http.post('app/signup', payload)
   .success(function(data) {
     $log.debug(data);

      $scope.email = null;
      $scope.password = null;
      $scope.signupForm.$setPristine(); //Set form to pristine mode
   });
```